# Is it possible to connect 300 devices with openthread?

Tags: openthread

I am looking for a stack allowing to connect several hundred devices,

Openthread has max numbers of hopes equal 16. 
Is it possible to extend that number to have 300 devices connected sequentially?
What are requirements to the chip in this case if possible or what limits the max number of connected routing devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Thread Protocol Specification](http://threadgroup.org/technology/ourtechnology#specifications) currently has a limit of 15 hops between routers (or 17 hops between end devices).  It is not possible to connect hundreds of devices sequentially.  At the same time, the Thread Protocol does connecting hundreds of end devices to each router.  However, in most practical cases, the number of end devices a router supports is determined by its memory resources.